# How can I restore a directory I accidentally deleted in git (command line)?

Tags: git, gitlab

I locally saved some files in my git directory on my computer yesterday. I must have played around with some git commands so that some text I wrote for my thesis that was is that directory is now gone along with its whole directory. Also some code I wrote..
I think it was never to be seen in the GitLab online website, telling me that it was never really saved in the git. But it isn't in my computer's local trash bin.

I have tried using `git log` but it does not show the directory I must have deleted. I also googled some options I have, including `git reset` and such. Nothing that gets me any further.

```
C:\Users\kanin\git_dir\Studis\Studis>git log
commit a6dedf6f4d79c6a7d476e7f8f19c6ab8e4e774b6 (HEAD -> Name, origin/Name)
Merge: 9cdad27 2b3e617
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Wed May 8 08:12:11 2019 +0200

    Merge branch 'hotfix_Names_branch' into 'Name'

    Wichtige <C3><84>nderung, da angrenzende R<C3><A4>ume nicht mehr auf optimierten Werten,...

    See merge request Name.Name/Studis!2

commit 9cdad275e74ce993f5e924a66ea776438415672b
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 15:50:32 2019 +0200

    Update send_emails.py

commit 420f7b8690edfbc5e1b7a29199a7e4992a836fa3
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 15:37:14 2019 +0200

    Update send_emails.py

commit 2b3e61780b4adb17e4a206d24c96e78161952b1d (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 15:35:59 2019 +0200

    Wichtige <C3><84>nderung, da angrenzende R<C3><A4>ume nicht mehr auf optimierten Werten, sondern jetzt gleich den Au<C3><9F>enwerten gesetzt werden

commit 503f140ba996e1c5f0dd7f948fec5ff9310dbcee
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 15:35:12 2019 +0200

    Upload New File

commit bf9ff0da6e9c63cccaaa9a407d77a1392ca16c10
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 15:23:03 2019 +0200

    Upload New File

commit f33f5f127ddd013c072081b57425bcf62446af07
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 15:21:06 2019 +0200

    Update room_skript.py

commit 8d04e1d93813e09b26ca25e1cbbf0f332c6111f5
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 14:55:59 2019 +0200

    Update views.py

commit 8550167a1fdf495b9b489a65eeb32461b1e30d21
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 14:42:23 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit adcc29061fd25268a6697c18818ec958e0a9fc6b
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 14:25:01 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit c4ff682b7b5c02f267a404761a7859b962e05f47
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 14:17:31 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit bc726c0a4dfd57f2268a4e57200152745db4b936
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 14:04:48 2019 +0200

    Update admin.py

commit 0952e0cc232c34d516af4d9ae8014ca7304552cb
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 13:55:33 2019 +0200

    Update models.py

commit 1f27c822a03fb6db878d8affb0efc287273e94c1
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 12:36:52 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit 3ad75b7c87c5631a22333fb0c917154c1764ca9e
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 12:28:12 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit 2db94184e3391816c5834cfdd895006df7085bbe
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 12:17:15 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit 147c600599291653a1128421e805f67f8c7eb710
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 12:16:32 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit 4a0415d68830cf3cc80456605321abf7c925e96f
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 12:09:20 2019 +0200

    Update settings.py

commit d5613870826d7bcc58b0b9b0a6ffe981c999ed51
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 10:51:01 2019 +0200

    no message

commit 415729575f78b901dac5bfcf49fd0bd24b9ff5d1
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue May 7 09:06:00 2019 +0200

    Delete activate.bat

commit fc549dfc6ba69afac0e7f48efbbbca88e37c3fc3
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Fri May 3 15:18:52 2019 +0200

    Upload New File

commit 8f0995a8a3d3af8908c567c728bf63c2e3934503
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Fri May 3 15:18:28 2019 +0200

    Delete activate.bat

commit 1e992cad9dff9a5f5e222324202de9ca8b5ed931
Author: Name Name Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Fri May 3 15:17:55 2019 +0200

    Upload New File

commit aae3ebdc9f351cac1105a11a66577368209ce247
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Fri May 3 11:42:41 2019 +0200

    Added Jiaos Code

commit 49a893979d0351dd77369f96b11ee8793577b68c
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Thu May 2 15:39:16 2019 +0200

    Summe musste hinzugef<C3><BC>gt werden, um Programm laufen lassen zu k<C3><B6>nnen

commit aa9d44bc77a24b75c897dd8f4581f1aeb6f0b29e
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Thu May 2 15:19:47 2019 +0200

    Adjusted the folder names

commit 6b27c49966ffe38a5da525f20d1b1622049d8713
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Thu May 2 15:12:36 2019 +0200

    optCO2 added

commit 77cee5adae628cc1f3ab61070c77ea22d0dc20e9
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Thu May 2 14:48:57 2019 +0200

    results-Dateien angepasst

commit ecb3e0a8af3a1a027aa09bf606155ff408b8783d
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue Apr 9 09:03:33 2019 +0200

    Added the user profile generator

commit 80821cd5f6548598cb80de3d998b0e1dd3f8b2fd
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Wed Apr 3 11:29:57 2019 +0200

    PA and Paper added

commit a3cd71d31cd2276b2328e931f1bd2949ef8de50a
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue Apr 2 08:38:43 2019 +0200

    Names n<C3><B6>tige Skripte

commit c749b4d8aa9f915d7870cfa5e297832c3cab21c3
Author: fni <Name.Name@eonerc.uni.de>
Date:   Thu Oct 4 15:29:41 2018 +0200

    EBC Data API added

commit 6aca36443fe61429601315496a51c324c185c041
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Thu Oct 4 10:59:59 2018 +0200

    EBC Data API added

commit 278a4f5c7cd2769ae475b386afb7a5330ef76da3
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue Oct 2 16:53:39 2018 +0200

    EBC Data API added

commit 104f402dce48ab4595f4547c038546d1d99e047a
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue Oct 2 16:21:33 2018 +0200

    EBC Data API added

commit 1c668dff152ec5a9eab3bf7b0327c3855039f284
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue Oct 2 14:35:00 2018 +0200

    all files added

commit f846a116fe34f51c6d6612bdd318e6c75e614a71
Author: Name Name <Name.Name@uni.de>
Date:   Tue Oct 2 14:23:08 2018 +0200

    Initial commit
(END)
```

I hope to get my files back :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you track your directory with git? if so, you can try:

```
git reflog
```

And for your code, depending on the IDE you are using, you could get it back via the local history.